# How to remove undefine margin and padding css

Tags: css

I made this card to display an image and info but there is a gap I can't remove using css

Here is the style and html

```css
.card-container>* {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.ratings {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  width: auto;
  height: fit-content;
}

.card-container img {
  width: 240px;
  height: 350px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card-container .stausbg {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="card-container">
  <img src='https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff' alt='card' />
  <span class="stausbg">Sold Out</span>
  <div class="ratings">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
    <p class="no-star">5</p>
    <p class="no-pp">(40)</p>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i>
    <p class="country">Usa</p>
  </div>
  <h5 class="title">Life lessons with jake</h5>
  <h6>From $200 / person</h6>
</div>
```

Here I have used aqua color as the background color of .ratings class. I want to remove the undefined space (margin padding) and apply my own style

[image: In this image show what space I exactly want to remove I have not add these spaces in my css how to remove this and why this happen]

Comment: Depending on the browser you are using, you may be able to see more info in the inspector. (right-click, choose inspect in edge and chrome, probably similar for firefox). This will let you see which element the padding/margin is coming from.

Comment: Once you know which element, you just need to set the padding and margin to 0

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

That space is coming from `p` tag. Just remove the margin.

```
.ratings p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: ok that works another thing what the gap between the image is and Sold-Out tag why it's not connected there is a small white space

Comment: Because images are 'inline' items, it includes a small space for descenders so the image baseline aligns with the text baseline. It's there to accomodate letters like 'j' and 'g'. Set it to a block element and the gap disappears.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set all the margins of the child items in the card to zero then, instead of using the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) (>) just use the [descendent combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator).

Quite a lot of developers use 'reset' rules to remove some of the weird, default [user agent stylesheet](https://meiert.com/en/blog/user-agent-style-sheets/) behaviours. Here's a quick [video](https://youtube.com/shorts/2lyDv0wOQuQ?feature=share) by Kevin Powell on this topic.

```css
.card-container * {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.ratings {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  width: auto;
  height: fit-content;
}

.card-container img {
  width: 240px;
  height: 350px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card-container .stausbg {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="card-container">
  <img src='https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff' alt='card' />
  <span class="stausbg">Sold Out</span>
  <div class="ratings">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
    <p class="no-star">5</p>
    <p class="no-pp">(40)</p>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i>
    <p class="country">Usa</p>
  </div>
  <h5 class="title">Life lessons with jake</h5>
  <h6>From $200 / person</h6>
</div>
```